# Lucene.net how to customize scoring

Tags: lucene.net

I have encountered an issue I seem to be unable solve with Lucene.net. We are using Lucene.net for auto-complete fields and would like for hits that start with searched word to appear on top of the list and other hits below.

Basically, what I want is that search results, starting with searched word, get a boost of some sort, to appear on top.

I have checked CustomScoreProvider and CustomScoreQuery, but I can't imagine how to use that to do what I want and there is no good example on how to implement it. But perhaps I am barking at the wrong tree, as something as trivial as this is most likely implemented by setting some property or something.

Answer (score 1):

You could attack this problem by changing your query instead of changing your scoring algorithm.

So your query which would have been:

```
Field:(this is a piece of text)
```

becomes:

```
Field:"this is a piece of text*"^2 OR Field:(this is a piece of text)
```